# Using apply() but getting class list answer

Tags: r, function, apply, tail

I have a series of columns in a `data.frame` of which I'd like to get the last value, excluding any NAs. The function I'm using to get this done is

```
    last_value <- function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1)
```

I'm using `apply()` to work this function across the 13 columns, for each observation (by row).

```
    df$LastVal<-apply(df[,c(116, 561, 1006, 1451, 1896, 2341, 2786, 3231, 
    3676, 4121, 4566, 5011, 5456)], 1, FUN=last_value)
```

My problem is that the output comes out as a list of 5336 (total observations), instead of just a vector of the last values by row. The answers seem to be there but again, in list form. I've used this function before and it's worked fine. When I `str()` my columns, they're all integers. 
Could  this function get tripped up if there are no values and only NAs?

I should add that when I `unlist()` the new variable, I get an error that says "replacement has 4649 rows, data has 5336", so I do think this might have something to do with NAs.

Comment: *Could this function get tripped up if there are no values and only NAs?* Yes, it can, I have just tried it and it does return a list.

Comment: For the case `all(is.na(x))` is `TRUE` return `NA` from your function.

Comment: @RuiBarradas how can I re-write the function to avoid that? I can't take out those rows that have NAs because they're vital for another analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to see what is the output of the function `last_value` as you have defined it with a row of `NA` values.

```
last_value <- function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1)

df <- matrix(1:24, 4)
df[2, ] <- NA
df <- as.data.frame(df)
apply(df, 1, last_value)
#[[1]]
#V6 
#21 
#
#[[2]]
#named integer(0)
#
#[[3]]
#V6 
#23 
#
#[[4]]
#V6 
#24
```

The problem is that the second member of this list is of length zero. This means that `unlist` will not solve the problem.
You have to test for a value of length zero.

```
last_value <- function(x) {
  y <- tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1)
  if(length(y) == 0) NA else y
}
apply(df, 1, last_value)
#[1] 21 NA 23 24
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 0):

You could include your function into a selection.

***Example***

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  4  7 10
2  2  5  8 11
3  3  6  9 12

last_value <- function(x) tail(x[!is.na(x)], 1)

> df[, last_value(c(3, 4))]  # selects last column
[1] 10 11 12
```

Test with `NA`.

```
df[2, 4] <- NA
> df[, last_value(c(3, 4))]
[1] 10 NA 12
```

If you're in need of an `apply()` approach use @Rui Barradas' well explained answer. Case you depend on speed, consider the benchmark of both solutions:

```
Unit: microseconds
                      expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq     max neval cld
  apply(df, 1, last_value) 166.095 172.6005 182.09241 177.449 188.2925 257.179   100   b
 df[, last_value(c(3, 4))]  32.147  33.4230  36.12764  34.699  35.5920 131.396   100  a
```

Apropos—for column wise use `sapply()`.

```
> sapply(df[, c(3, 4)], FUN=last_value)
V3 V4 
 9 12
```

Comment: Just for completeness sake `sapply` sometimes also returns lists. IMO if you want to enjoy the apply-family stick to `lapply`, sometimes `tapply` and if you get a list use `do.call(cbind,mylappy_output)` or `rbind` instead of `cbind`.

Comment: Hi @jaySf , thanks for the answer but it's not quite what I wanted to do. This should be for each of your three observations and produce a vector resulting in 10,11,12.